# Выбрать значние из списка

Tags: python, list

Есть список `l = [10,20,10,10,1,5,10,2,2,5,5]`
Для того чтобы получить последнее зачение из `l` надо написать `l[-1] = 5`
А как получить максимальное (или минимальное) значение например за последних 5 значений из списка? (это будет 10 для максимального). При этом оставить возможность, что если все же набрать не 5 последних значений, а 1, то макс-мин значение будет последним, тоесть 5.

Пример:

```
Для l = [10,20,10,10,1,5,10,2,2,5,5]

l макс 5 = 10
l мин 7 = 1
l мин 1 = 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто выбери количество символов котрые хочешь отобразить с конца. а потом с помощью функций  min(), max() сможешь получить значение.

```
l = [10,20,10,10,1,5,10,2,2,5,5]
b = l[-5:] # Отобразить последние 5 символов
print(max(b))
```

Comment: Только не символов, а значений в данном случае. Надо поправить копипасту )